# Postgres БД c колонкой типа interval

Tags: java, postgresql, дата, jdbc

СУБД PostgreSQL

Имеется колонка типа `interval hour to minute`
Как в нее поместить значение типа Date `01:22:00`

Имеется код

```
String query ="INSERT INTO table values(?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setDate(1, date);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Но вылетает ошибка о невозможности засунуть туда этот тип

Comment: Сделал в  String query ="INSERT INTO table values(?::INTERVAL)"; и все вставилось как надо. А может еть лучше предложение?

Comment: Сам спросил, сам ответил - это по-нашему! :)

Comment: Посмотрите PGInterval https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGInterval.html `PGInterval pgi = (PGInterval)resultSet.getObject("interval_field");` `preparedStatement.setObject(1, pgi);`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал в `String query = "INSERT INTO table values(?::INTERVAL)";` и все вставилось как надо. А может есть лучше предложение?